# Dynamic key value pair find in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm facing a problem in searching for dynamic key value pairs using `.find` method in mongoDB.
here is my array of objects which the key value pairs can be increased...

```js
[ 
    {
        "key" : "dynamicKey1",
        "value": "dynamicValue1"
    },
    {
        "key" : "dynamicKey2",
        "value": "dynamicValu2"
    },
...

]
```

I wish to get the result in a way that satisfies all the key value pair conditions. Something like find all documents from collection that satisfies these conditions.

So my API is this:

```js
app.post('/search/:name',  (req, res) => {

const collectionName = req.params.name;
  async.eachSeries(req.body, (item, callback) => {
  
    const database = client.db("databaseName");
    const result = database.collection(collectionName).find({ [item.key]: item.value }).toArray();
    result.then((doc) => {
    res.json(doc)
      })
    callback();
  });
});
```

the result returns two or more promises but I only need those documents that satisfies all `.find` queries as the result.

How should I solve it?

Thanks

Here is Insomnia POST request Image: [Insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmSxh.jpg)

Comment: Can you please explain what actually you are trying to do, the query, and returning only one doc a little more?

Comment: @kgangadhar yes, so I have an array of objects with keys and values, the keys and values can be different each time the API is called. so I need to get only those documents from collection that satisfies all the key value condition. so the above API runs for each key value pair object and returns the union of all `.find` method. I would like to have only one result that satisfies all key value pairs conditions, in simple word the intersection of all queries. I have tried aggregate but dont know how to write it correctly.

Comment: Please check the Image I have added to the post

Comment: I recommend that MongoDB Atlas Search with wildcard paths. It's much easier, feature rich for the use case, and faster https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/path-construction#wildcard-field-search

Comment: @Nice-Guy I have checked it. This is also helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Image you provided your data is of the following format in the database:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "region": "Auckland",
        "anzsic_descriptor":"Agriculture",
        "gas": "carbon diaoxide equivalents",
        "units":"kilotonnes",
        "magnitude":"carbon diaoxide equivalents",
        "year": "2011",
        "data_val": "764.3"
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "region": "Canterbury",
        "anzsic_descriptor":"Agriculture",
        "gas": "carbon diaoxide equivalents",
        "units":"kilotonnes",
        "magnitude":"carbon diaoxide equivalents",
        "year": "2011",
        "data_val": "6823.16"
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "region": "Bay of Plenty",
        "anzsic_descriptor":"Agriculture",
        "gas": "carbon diaoxide equivalents",
        "units":"kilotonnes",
        "magnitude":"carbon diaoxide equivalents",
        "year": "2011",
        "data_val": "1477.94"
    }
   ...........
]
```

The `/search/:name` is receiving a body which is an array in the below format:

```
[{
    "key": "year",
    "value": "2011"
}, {
    "key": "data_val",
    "value": "764.3"
}]
```

You need to use a query generate as follows to generate your query first before the DB query:

```js
const generateQuery = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((result, item) => {
        const {key, value } = item;
        result[key] = value;
        return result;
    }, {});
};

console.log(generateQuery([{"key": "year","value": "2011"},{"key": "data_val","value": "764.3"}]))
```

The DB query for the generated query looks like this: [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Gu4TqDtCRa).

Then use this generated query to get the result in the endpoint, all these changes looks like below:

```
const generateQuery = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((result, item) => {
        const { key, value } = item;
        result[key] = value;
        return result;
    }, {});
};


app.post('/search/:name', (req, res) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const collectionName = req.params.name;
        const queryArry = req.body // [{"key": "year","value": "2011"},{"key": "data_val","value": "764.3"}]
        const query = generateQuery(queryArry);
        const database = client.db("databaseName");
        database.collection(collectionName).find(query).then(result => {
            return resolve(result);
        }).catch(e => {
            reject(e);
        });
    }).catch(e => {
        reject(e);
    })
});
```

Comment: Correct, Thanks for helping :)